# Getting on the Riley Train

Tags: riddle

> Our prefix is a leader
>   Our infix is a name
>   Our suffix is risky
>   My whole can be sung.
>
> Four of us are missing here
>   Could you find them?
>   The longer I am doing this,
>   The more you will see!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are writing about the

> alphabet

Our prefix is a leader

> alpha - the first letter of the Greek alphabet

Our infix is a name

> abe - often short for Abraham

Our suffix is risky

> bet - gamble

My whole can be sung.

> Singing the alphabet helps to remember it.

Four of us are missing here - The longer I am doing this, The more you will see!

> j, q, v, z are missing, and the more you write, the more of the alphabet you'll reveal.

Comment: Nicely done! This is the correct answer